# Creating comma delimited file - trailing delimiter

Tags: java, string

I want to write a file using String array. i have written code that is adding an extra delimiter at the end.

```
for(String data : fieldsData ){
    data="\""+data+"\"";
    writer.write(data);
    writer.write(",");
}
writer.newLine();
```

For example, for this input

> a,b,c

I am getting this output

> "a","b","c",

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - so you want the quotes but not the last `,`?

Comment: please clarify your question. what kind of output do want for your `a,b,c` input?

Comment: desired output --- "a","b","c"

Comment: its pretty clear what the output is, he just said he's trying to get rid of the last comma. Surely we are smart enough to put this together ourselves without being pedantic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a basic for loop to determine where the last index occurs

```
for (int i = 0; i < fieldsData.length - 1; i++) {
    writer.write("\"" + fieldsData[i] + "\",");
}
writer.write("\"" + fieldsData[fieldsData.length - 1] + "\"");
```

Comment: why use an if statement. you could go up to length-1 on the For and then do one write outside of the For with out the ",". no?

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 way:

```
writer.write(Arrays.stream(fieldsData)
      .map(s -> "\"" + s + "\"")
      .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

afterwards, you can use a regex to replace the last comma by checking for a comma followed by whitespace, then replace it with an empty string. something like:

```
for(String data : fieldsData ){
data="\""+data+"\""+",";
}
data.replaceAll(",\\s", "");
writer.write(data)
```